# How to use vanilla JavaScript to click a div like button on an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently trying to automate a game called Lyrics Training (https://www.lyricstraining.com/) using a JavaScript extension, and I am able to get the words that are from the button through some other code but I am currently struggling with clicking the "button" because it is for some reason classified as a DIV in the HTML code. I was wondering whether there was a way or a function that would allow me to click it so I could finish the automation? Thanks!

So far I have this code that would work if the button was an actual button:

```
let firstChoice = document.getElementsByClassName("slot s1")[0];
    let secondChoice = document.getElementsByClassName("slot s2")[0];
    let thirdChoice = document.getElementsByClassName("slot s3")[0];
    let fourthChoice = document.getElementsByClassName("slot s4")[0];

    // the click function isn't working
    for(let i = 0; i < click_order.length; i++){
        let word = click_order[i];
        if(firstChoice.innerHTML === word){
            firstChoice.click();
        }else if(secondChoice.innerHTML === word){
            secondChoice.click();
        }else if(thirdChoice.innerHTML === word){
            thirdChoice.click();
        }else if(fourthChoice.innerHTML === word){
            fourthChoice.click();
        }
    }
```

Someone had also told me that I could inject code into the website and make the divs have the attribute 'role="button"', which I did using this code, which unfortunately did not succeed:

```
                    let firstChoice = document.getElementsByClassName("slot s1")[0];
                    let secondChoice = document.getElementsByClassName("slot s2")[0];
                    let thirdChoice = document.getElementsByClassName("slot s3")[0];
                    let fourthChoice = document.getElementsByClassName("slot s4")[0];
                    // add role="button" to all choices
                    firstChoice.setAttribute("role", "button");
                    secondChoice.setAttribute("role", "button");
                    thirdChoice.setAttribute("role", "button");
                    fourthChoice.setAttribute("role", "button");

 for(let i = 0; i < click_order.length; i++){
        let word = click_order[i];
        if(firstChoice.innerHTML === word){
            firstChoice.click();
        }else if(secondChoice.innerHTML === word){
            secondChoice.click();
        }else if(thirdChoice.innerHTML === word){
            thirdChoice.click();
        }else if(fourthChoice.innerHTML === word){
            fourthChoice.click();
        }
    }
```

This is how the HTML for the button is structured in the website itself that is causing me issues:

```
<div class="slot s1" style=""><b style="opacity: 1; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">Hope</b><ol></ol></div>
```

(That is 1/4 of the slots, each contains the word right before the  tag)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: As far as I knew click() should work. The click() method is defined at the HTMLElement class, so it should work for Divs as well. Nevertheless, reading MDN documentation states that "When click() is used with supported elements (such as an <input>), it fires the element's click event. " So it might imply that for not supported objects It wont fire the click event. Maybe you can try inserting a fake button in the div and making click; the click event will bubble. Also you could try using other events, such as mouseDown, mouseUp, touchStart etc; maybe the app is not listening exactly to a click

Answer (score 0):

Grab all button node and do loop for each event

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.button').forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert(e.target.innerText)
  })
})
```

```html
<button class="button">B 1</button>
<button class="button">B 2</button>
<button class="button">B 3</button>
<button class="button">B 4</button>
```